# Django logging configuration requires filters to be specified on handlers

Tags: django, logging

I'm configuring logging for my Django project, here's the settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            # 'filters': [],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
```

With `'filters': []` commented out, no errors are logged to the console. Uncommenting that line makes everything work as expected.

[Python's logging.config docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) would have me believe that `logging` is optional on handlers.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have missed the key in your loggers dict. I am using the follwing dictionary and its working fine.

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What key are you talking about?

Comment: in my dict the key is "django.request"...why is your "loggers" dict has no key?

Comment: Because I want a 'catch all' logger, i.e. all error messages should be emailed to me (not just ones from `django.request` or deeper).